# How to connect Databricks Database with Springboot application using JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, databricks, azure-databricks

facing issue with integrating our Springboot JPA supported application with Databricks delta database.

Below are the steps and setting we did for the integration.

When we are starting the springboot application we are getting a warning as  :

```
HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. 
([Databricks][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature.)
```

and the application gets started.

When interacting with DB for any CRUD operation we are getting exception : `Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Databricks][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature`.

Driver used: `com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver`

Url:  `jdbc:databricks://************************ t:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/778046939806498/0307-074105-********;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=*****************`

Dialect : `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Below are other drivers that we tried as well  suggested in databricks-jdbc-driver-install-and-configuration-guide:

```
com.databricks.client.jdbc.DataSource
com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver
com.databricks.client.jdbc42.DataSource
```

Also we would like to highlight that we are able to make single connection and able to perform CRUD operation with custom queries but not with Spring Data Jpa.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Databricks JDBC driver doesn't support autoCommit which is set to default to true in HikariCP.

So you need to configure autoCommit to false explicitly in your HikariCP configuration.

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.0.0/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-

Comment: Thanks for response, didnt worked for me...